# vlookp using indirect on static path, changing sheet name

Tags: excel, vlookup

So I want to use a vlookup into another workbook and the sheets change name from week to week.
The path to the workbook is the same always, it is only the sheet names that needs to change.
what I have made is this:
`=VLOOKUP($H2;INDIRECT("'"&"\\Static path\folder\[workbook2.xlsm]"&"$j1"&"'"&"!"&"D:O");12;0)`
H2 being what it should look for and J1 being the sheets name, as it changes.
In this case J1 = Last Week.
The result is just #REF 
What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you are opening the `\\Static path\folder\workbook2.xlsm`? `INDIRECT` needs the workbook opened to get references from it.

Comment: Still just a #REF. Just noticed something though. My J1 isn't marked on J1( with the coloured frame) does that mean my line of code isn't really looking at J1 for reference?

Comment: Yes `&"$j1"&` should be without quotation marks to concatenate the content of `J1` instead concatenating the string "$j1". But nevertheless `INDIRECT` cannot get references from closed workbooks.

Comment: UPDATE: I just removed the "" around J1. that worked. now I just get a #NA instead. even though the other workbook is open at the same time.

Comment: `#N/A` means that the value of `$H2` cannot be found in `'\\Static path\folder\[workbook2.xlsm]SheetNameFromJ1'` in column `D`.

Comment: Minor mistake from my part. just added $j$1 so it wouldn't change. it now works as it is supposed to. thank you for your assistance Axel. just needed someone else to point out my mistakes.